# Difference between adaptive thresholding and normal thresholding in opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, threshold

I have this gray video stream:
[image]

The histogram of this image:

[image]

The thresholded image by :

```
  threshold( image, image, 150, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );
```

i get :

[image]

Which i expect.

When i do adaptive thresholding with :

```
adaptiveThreshold(image, image,255,ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, CV_THRESH_BINARY,15,-5);
```

i get :

[image]

Which looks like edge detection and not thresholding. What i expected was black and white areas . So my question is, why does this look like edge detection and not thresholding.

thx in advance

Comment: Adaptive Threshold works very well. Even much better than a static threshold especially for images from a camera. But it depends on what you want to do. Your image is a VERY bad example. Your last image only shows that your parameters are completely wrong. Your first parameter mut have a significantly higher value to avoid that "edge detection" effect. There are two parameters to be passed to adaptiveThreshold() : Both affect the result. Experiment with them until you understand what they do. And use a better image for testing!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adaptive Threshold works like [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html):

> The function transforms a grayscale image to a binary image according
>   to the formulas:
>
> ```
>     THRESH_BINARY
> ```
>
> [image: THRESH_BINARY]
>
> ```
>     THRESH_BINARY_INV
> ```
>
> [image: THRESH_BINARY_INV]
>
> where T(x,y) is a threshold calculated individually for each pixel.

Threshold works [differently](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#threshold):

> The function applies fixed-level thresholding to a single-channel array.

So it sounds like adaptiveThreshold calculates a threshold pixel-by-pixel, whereas threshold calculates it for the whole image -- it measures the whole image by one ruler, whereas the other makes a new "ruler" for each pixel.

Comment: If i would do a blob analysis on the image which has been thresholded adaptively. Would the middle square be 1 blob ? (I'm doing surface detection, still have to see how the blob detection works in opencv, that's why i ask it first)

Comment: I don't know that it would, probably the white specs would be. Look at this book, page 231, section 6.2 for a comparison of blob analysis with different thresholding: http://books.google.com/books?id=dbPaBUaLzcIC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=image+blob+analysis+adaptive+threshold&source=bl&ots=_yVSlzAvOP&sig=vbbz2jac82rMGn1CpCXx1JJnTdI&hl=en&ei=gSTVTsGaN-OuiQK0vNWyDg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=image%20blob%20analysis%20adaptive%20threshold&f=false

Comment: I still do not get the behavior. What makes adaptive threshold different from lets say, applying a Gaussian blur then subtracting it and do a normal threshold. According to what the document describes they should be the same, but they are not, maybe sigma is a very big number.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue doing adaptive thresholding for OCR purposes. (sorry this is Python not C++)

```
img = cv.LoadImage(sys.argv[1])
bwsrc = cv.CreateImage( cv.GetSize(img), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
bwdst = cv.CreateImage( cv.GetSize(img), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)

cv.CvtColor(img, bwsrc, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
cv.AdaptiveThreshold(bwsrc, bwdst, 255.0, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY, cv.CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,11)
cv.ShowImage("threshhold", bwdst)
cv.WaitKey()
```

The last paramter is the size of the neighborhood used to calculate the threshold for each pixel. If your neighborhood is too small (mine was 3), it works like edge detection. Once I made it bigger, it worked as expected. Of course, the "correct" size will depend on the resolution of your image, and size of the features you're looking at.

Comment: On a hunt I found this answer, can you please tell us what kind of datatypes are used for img, bwscr, and bwdst? Is it Mat ?

Comment: I don't recall exactly, but here's a script I was working on around the time I answered this question: https://github.com/ludflu/ocrprep/blob/master/ocrprep.py

Comment: I only see now that it is in python, I thought it is C++